# Filtering out Area codes in Excel by VBA

Tags: vba, excel

need some assistance. It's been a very long time since I've done scripting/coding and really rusty now.

**Issue:** I have a spreadsheet(Excel Visual Basic) that contains call(s) over a month(Over 30k records). My goal is to filter out calls that have specific area codes (toll free, local calls...etc) and calculate how much they owe from calling long distance.

Additionally, this is a retirement home and the end-user(s) do not  enter phone numbers correctly. I need to either strip 3-4 digits at the start of numbers..

Example: 1800-XXX-XXXX or 800-XXX-XXXX | 1605-XXX-XXXX

Here's the code I currently have, I'm lost on how to incorporate the 3-4 digits in the area and have it parse each record in Column H by the first 3-4 digits

***Phone numbers are stored in Column H***

**Array TFL will store all the area codes I need to filter out.**

```
Sub CleanEntry()
Dim i As Integer
Dim TFL As Variant
TFL = Array("1800", "1877")

For i = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1

If Left(Cells(i, "H"), 4) Like TFL(i) Then
Sheet1.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Advanced/auto filter?

Comment: Would I be able to use Left/Right to have it filter out area codes?

Comment: You don't need left/right. Try it. Fairly intuitive. I am referring to the filter button on the data tab of your ribbon.

Comment: I'll look it up. Would it accept array usage for criteria?

Comment: Oh, I think so... but you'd need VBA for that.

Comment: I'm doing this in VBA so that's fine.

Comment: That's my point. I think that's overkill.

Comment: The sheet I have was only 15 days elapsed time and gathered 30k records. They need it filtered down to charge tenants for their long distance time used. I need to filter down all the records that are local/toll free in order to split data for each residents then calculate how much they need to be charged.

Comment: So 60k for a month? That's doable. Maybe it won't suffice. Try it. If not, come back and we can do more work if necessary^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd personally use a regular expression for this:

```
Sub CleanEntry()
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim filter As New RegExp
    filter.Pattern = "^1?(8(77|00))|605" 'Or whatever else you need to match.

    For i = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If filter.Test(Trim$(Cells(i, "H").Value)) Then
            Sheet1.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Note:** You'll need to add a reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5.

Comment: *Edit Figured it out. Had to Alt+F11 to gain access.      I'm new to Visual Basic. My reference button is not active. I'm using VB by hitting macros on Excel 2010.

Comment: It's working great so far! Thanks! I'm still looking through each record so far making sure that long distances calls were not deleted, but it's looking good.

Comment: @CeFu - See the edit.  I forgot to anchor the regex to the start of the string.